# Different colors possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

I am given $n$ number of candies . And candies can be any one of the $k$ colors i.e. there are candies of $k$ different colors . How many possibilities are there such that on each selection of any random number of candies, there is at least $1$ candy of each color ?

Is it as simple as calculating $nCk$ ?
I believe this is easy, but I cant get my thinking hat on at the moment. Explaination is appreciated!

Comment: No, it is not $_nC_k$. Have you heard of stars and bars formula ?

Comment: Nope . Sorry . I'll check it out !

Comment: Here's a link. See if it suffices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $k$ needs to be $\ge n$.

I think you want the # of ways $k$ candies can be chosen so that each of $n$ colors is represented. Using stars and bars, you get $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$

If, instead you want to know the probability of getting all colors if you choose *k* candies randomly, it becomes the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem)